# bijective continuous map from X to Y and Y to X

Tags: general-topology

Suppose X and Y two topological space. If there exists bijective  continuous map f  from X to Y and a map g from Y to X which is also bijective continuous. Is it true that X and Y homeomorphic?

Comment: Um... yes? If f is bijective then $f^{-1}$ is bijective so don't need to specify g.

Comment: What's to try?  It's the definition.

Comment: g may be different from inverse of f

Comment: @fleablood I don't think so. It is not stated that $g$ is the inverse of $f$, nor that $f,g$ have continuous inverse.

Comment: how can we sure inverse of f continuous

Comment: i tried tried many example but fail...

Comment: like F Bernstein thm which says if we have  inj map from X to Y and an inj map from Y to X then they are equivalent.

Comment: if it is not true..can someone give counter example

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ need not be homeomorphic. See [this MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/30661/non-homeomorphic-spaces-that-have-continuous-bijections-between-them) for counterexamples.

Comment: We can setup bijections from $S^1$ to $\Bbb R$ but they are not homeomorphic.

Comment: no you cant  circle is compact but its conts image R is not compact